# Facebook session not opened in oncreate()

Tags: android, facebook

I am implementing facebook login through login-button and UiLifecycleHelper ([as of this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/)).

Is it possible to check loginstatus in onCreate() or do a have to wait until onResume()? Because as of now my check in onCreate() always says sassion is not opened. In onResume() however it is fine.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initiate helper
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, this);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Always says false
    Log.i(TAG, "Session onCreate " + Session.getActiveSession().isOpened());
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();

    // Here session is opened
    Log.i(TAG, "Session onResume " + Session.getActiveSession().isOpened());
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a separate thread to do the work and call within `onCreate()` and see if that works.

Comment: You could try get Session.getActiveSession, check for null and/or isOpened, if null try get session from openActiveSessionFromCache and check again...